# How to set up a database in a LAN connection using MS SQL 2008 and MS VStudio 2010 C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am making a LAN Chat and E-mail program ( Windows Forms Application ) in MS VStudio 2010 C# and it would run in a LAN.

I was wondering how to set up a database for this. There would be a server computer and client computers.

I also want to know how to access the database in the server from the client computers (i.e. what is the form of the connection string)

Comment: For connection strings see [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Isn't wise to make your clients to connect directly to you application database. Can you create an service layer and make your clients to access it through WCF for instance?

Comment: Please for the sake of Turing, don't use databases for messaging, it's one of the worst anti-patterns around.

Comment: @linkerro i will not use my database for messaging, just for the email.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a great reference](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) for all your connection string questions.

A typical connection string will look like:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

In this case `myServerAddress` would be the address of a server that the clients can reach. If you install Sql Server on that machine you will be able to access it from client machines.

If you are using `Sql Server Express`, you have to make some configuration changes to your server machine because Express by default doesn't allow remote connections. You can find the info you need [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/17/enabling-remote-sql-express-2008-network-connections-on-vista.aspx)